# Capture Calling statement as a variable

Tags: hana

Want to know if it is at all possible to capture the calling query... example

```
SELECT SITE,NAME,COUNT(ITEMS) FROM SQLVIEW1 WHERE NAME = 'JIM'
```

in the SQL view it has something like this

```
DECLARE VAR1
```

where VAR1 would equal the above query that triggered the procedure.

```
"SELECT SITE,NAME,COUNT(ITEMS) FROM SQLVIEW1 WHERE NAME = 'JIM'"
```

Comment: For what kind of DB? MysQL, PostgresQL, SQLite, etc?

Comment: @user2180833: HANA, see the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such variable.

You could find out the currently executing statement through clever joins of system tables:

```sql
SELECT STATEMENT_STRING FROM SYS.M_TRANSACTIONS AS TR
INNER JOIN SYS.M_PREPARED_STATEMENTS AS ST
ON TR.CURRENT_STATEMENT_ID = ST.STATEMENT_ID
WHERE TR.CONNECTION_ID = CURRENT_CONNECTION
```

However, it seems conceptually wrong to me, to have a view depend on its calling statement. Maybe explain what you want to achieve and someone can suggest a better solution?

Comment: Really more of an experiment... if certain columns are used in the select string it triggers another query...